# Get surrounding location details using GPS?

Tags: android, gps

I'm new to Android; I'm able to get the current location using GPS but how do I get the surrounding location details using the current location obtained? Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=business+near+city");
startActivity(intent);
```

After geo you put your coordinates, and after q= you input your search tearms, like tourism+city. This will fire up the Google Maps app with the points of interest.

If you want to use a maps view inside your application, you would need to get the data from some service, like your own. However you could pull the data from Google's ajax search like this

[http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&rsz=large&gl=pl&q=tourism+chicago](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/local?v=1.0&rsz=large&gl=pl&q=tourism%20chicago)

more info :
http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html#_fonje_local

This will give you results that have geo-coordinates and you would need to make a way of parsing the results and maybe get them into a database.

hope it helps...